# how to make wpf webview scroll like webbrowser?

Tags: c#, wpf, webview, wpf-controls, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to use a `Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView` control in a wpf desktop application.  It seems to use substantially less resouces than the webbrowser control and is much more up to date, being based on edge.  However, unlike the webbrowser control, it won't scroll unless selected.  i.e. When the mouse is over the webbrowser I can scroll up and down without selecting first but webview ignores the mouse wheel if it isn't the current selected control.

Using VS2019 the following code demonstrates the problem.

```
<Window x:Class="test0.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:WPF="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="1024">

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="hello world" Height="100" />
            <WPF:WebView Source="https://bing.com" Height="250" />
            <WebBrowser Source="https://bing.com" Height="250" />
        </StackPanel>
     </Grid>

</Window>
```

On running, both browser controls will scroll when the mouse cursor is over.  After clicking the button (removing the focus from either of the browsers), only the webbrowser control scrolls on mouseover.

Is there any workaround to fix this?

Using: .NET Framework 4.7.2 and Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView 5.1.1

Comment: That's strange as it works for me. What version of framework and toolkit are you using?

Comment: @Tronald Framework 4.7.2 and Toolkit 5.1.1 Are you sure it works for you?  Initially, both controls will scroll without selecting but after clicking the button, only the webbrowser will scroll.  The Webview ignores the mousewheel unless it is clicked on first.

Comment: I just tried it with matching versions and it still works for me (I also confirmed I lost focus by clicking the button). That's really strange. Do you think it could be an Edge issue? Maybe certain versions of Edge don't focus on mouse over.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Edge and it scrolls just fine on mouseover.  It's only the webview that doesn't.  Actually if I use a webview in a UWP app, it works.  It's just using the webview in a WPF app that fails.  At least for me.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem as well, seems to work fine at my end!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved! But nothing to do with VS, or framework versions etc.  It seems the touchpad driver doesn't play nice with the webview control under some circumstances.  It was remiss of me not to mention I was using a touchpad vs a genuine mouse but it never occurred to me there would be a difference.  Until I plugged in a mouse and there was no problem.

Anyway, the solution was to download and install precision touchpad drivers as per:

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-precision-touchpad-drivers

Which solved the problem... Until windows decided to "update" the driver back to the old one.  The only way to stop windows doing this was to disable "Automatic driver downloads" as per:

https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/disable-automatic-driver-downloads-on-windows-10

I wish I had mentioned I was using a touchpad as I suspect the problem might have been more easily reproducible for those who aren't using precision touchpad drivers.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a sample page and also give code in the answer as per your requirement please review existing code and get back to me if there are any queries.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:WPF="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="720" Width="1280">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="hello world" Height="100" />
        <!--<WPF:WebView Source="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8" Height="250" />-->
        <WPF:WebView Source="https://bing.com" Height="250" />
        <WebBrowser Source="https://bing.com" Height="250"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Bing is a one view site so the search panel is not able to scroll even if you can directly check in on web browser.

**Edit:**

Can you please check your windows version and SDK as per requirements

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.ui.interop.webviewcontrol

Windows version: 1809

SDK version: 17763

Added values:

AddInitializeScript

**GotFocus**

**LostFocus**

Comment: Doesn't work.   Incidentally, it doesn't matter what website is used as the source, the lack of scrolling is the same.

Comment: Can you please check your windows version and SDK as per requirements [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.ui.interop.webviewcontrol).

Comment: Windows 10 (1903) version: 10.0.18362  Works perfectly in a UWP app.  Just not in a wpf.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe this is what you're looking for.

You'll want to define Row Definitions for your Grid as you see below and assign the what I assume is going to be your toolbar with "hello world" into Grid Row 0 and your web browser into Grid Row 1 rather than using the Stack Panel in this scenario (see code below).

Let me know if that helps or if you need it done a little differently I'm sure I could help you figure that out.

[Grid Row Definitions - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid.rowdefinitions?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Controls_Grid_RowDefinitions)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:WPF="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Content="hello world" Height="100" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <WebBrowser Source="https://bing.com" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <WPF:WebView Source="https://bing.com" Grid.Row="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Also I would like to point out that I did run this myself and it worked.

Comment: Still doesn't work.  Maybe it's some strange obscure bug with my synaptics mouse driver... One more thing, if I click on the webbrowser, I am still able to scroll on mouseover the webview.  It's only if I click any other control that webview seems to ignore the mousewheel.

Comment: Yeah something strange is happening there it would seem.

You may be able to rule out the mouse driver by trying another mouse if you have one available. I've looked over the other people's code too who have answered and it runs for me as well. 

There'd be a lot to rule out. Ensuring is everything up to date, VS2019, SDK's in use etc. I'm trying to duplicate the conditions you're describing now. I think Ishan Patel is onto something with the Focus idea.

I hope using grids helped with the layout as well. I noticed that issue when I first loaded it up.

Comment: I confirmed my VS 2019 is up to date here's the relevant output for you to compare versions too. It's working fine on mine and I can't get it to duplicate this bug either. I tried switching mouses and messing around with the tab button to see if I could somehow mess up the focus of the elements. No issues with the code I provided. You bringing up the mouse too makes me think that's worth ruling out. Have you tried anything else not listed on the post yet?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.3.9 I see the SDK and Windows versions listed below. Something to just rule out mostly.

Comment: Another thing to rule out quick too would be the .NET framework version you're currently using. To clarify this ran fine for me in Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.03752.

Answer (score 0):

I have read your query and try to figure out some issues. Kindly check your windows and SDK version [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.ui.interop.webviewcontrol).

- Your windows version must have above or **1809**
- Your SDK version must have above or **17763**

Please let me know in case any doubt or confusion.

Comment: Windows and SDK versions are above the minimum: Windows 10 1903 SDK (10.0.18362.0)